# .NET Remoting - Redirect Message / Host Redundancy

Tags: .net, redirect, .net-2.0, .net-remoting

I'm trying to accomplish some form of redirection of messages in .NET Remoting.
[image]

As you can see in the image I would like for the client to send a message to the provider (which is the only URI that the client has to know about), which will then redirect this to host1. Here's the tricky part; the provider will keep track of which host is alive (by exposing a register/unregister remoting-method to the hosts), in other words the provider has to be able to dynamically change which URI it should redirect the message to.

I have been attempting to solve the problem by creating a host in the provider that the client sends messages to, and then a client (in the provider) that implements a custom proxy ([by inheriting from RealProxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.remoting.proxies.realproxy?view=netframework-4.8)) that will redirect messages to the currently preferred host. However, I keep coming back to the problem about dynamically changing URI and I get the feeling that I'm just missing some easy, but vital, part that will solve this problem without turning it into a big hairy monster.

Any tips/hints will be much appreciated!

Comment: Which version of the .NET Framework are you using? `If >= 3.0`, you might want to consider using WCF instead of the now deprecated .NET Remoting.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that. I'm using .Net 2.0.

Comment: OK. You should add the appropriate tag for that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I'm taking another, simplified, approach on this. The provider will be removed and instead the client will try to access host1 directly. In case of a SocketException, which is what it will get when the host doesn't reply, then put it in quarantine for X minutes and try with the next host. If all hosts are down, re-throw the exception.